# Host SMBus controller is not enabled

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, blacklist, smbus

I have maked a backup from my **VMWare Virtual Machine**. I have imported it into the source folder.

At the first time i can start the VM, it shows me the error, but i can start it. But when i reboot the VM, the error shows me, but the VM dont start.

shows to me and the VM dont start, error :

> **"piix4_smbus 0000:00:007.3" Host SmBus controller not enabled!"**

I have tried to add into the `blacklist.conf` file this line : `blacklist i2c-piix4`

But it still dont works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the dash in `blacklist i2c-piix4` to an underscore, like `blacklist i2c_piix4`? That may also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wanted to post this on a ubuntu forum, but didn't have enough reputation, so I just post it here (same error on kali linux)

So this just happend to me and I wanted to share it with y'all, perhaps it helps somebody:

So I run Kali Linux in a VMware enviroment on Windows and I was away from my computer. It went
to sleep (while transfering files to a shared windows folder) and when I came back it only
showed a black screen. So I did a restart but then a blue screen happend. After restarting my
host I went and tried to power up the kali linux OS, then I got the following error:

```
Piix4_SMBus: 000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller bus not enabled
```

not only that, it was stuck on a initramfs console. After trying all the stuff I found related
to this error (adding the blacklist stuff in any imagionable way) I went back to the error.
If you are in the initramfs console then type exit. It should show a error what is happening.

For me it showed that the /dev/sda1 had problems and I had to run fsck manually. What I did
not mention before is that I managed to get inside the kali linux OS by adding the original ISO
as a CD to VMware. I then entered the boot menu with F2 and changed the boot order to have CD on top.

You then get additional advanced boot options, also the recovery kali linux OS. (the graphical didn't work,
just use the console one) follow all the steps and enter the /dev/sda1 as root console. Then type the following
commands:

```
mount -o remount,ro /
fsck
```

it should do a fsck scan now and for me it showed a lot of errors. Just press enter on every error and then do
a reboot. Change the boot order in the BIOS again and then it should boot normally.

Comment: Why did you need reputation in order to post your answer? Was you "forum" in "Ask Ubuntu"?